# Dataflow results in sharepoint 429 error when using SelectRows statement

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

My team is reading data using a Power BI dataflow from sharepoint into a single table with disabled load that consists of multiple Records. Let's call that table "Extract table". Then all the other tables read from the "Extract table", to avoid having multiple connections reading the same data from Sharepoint simultaneously.

[image: Failing architecture]

The problem is that our biggest table in the dataflow (Transform table 2) succeeds and does a full refresh in 15-30 mins, having literally >10 times the data compared to the rest of the tables. I tested this by removing all the other tables and running the dataflow with only this large table.

If I want to refresh any of the other tables that we have, although they are smaller, the dataflow fails after 1-3 hours and gives us a 429 error from Sharepoint, indicating we are making too many requests. The only difference between our working dataflow and the rest that don't work is that the others involve a "Table.SelectRows" statement. We have noticed again and again that adding a SelectRows statement in the downstream tables make our dataflows fail.

I tested removing the upstream "Extract table" and moving all its logic to a single table that normally fails, to test if that is related to the issue. The dataflow took longer than expected to complete for that small table, around 35 mins, but it completed a full refresh. So to me it seems that the problem is the presence of the SelectRows statement in combination with one of the following:

1. Reading from an upstream table.
2. Reading from an upstream table with Disabled Load.
3. Using a Transform file in an upstream table with disabled load.

Below is a picture with three scenarios that I have tested, that demonstrate that the problem is not in my table's logic, but that it's related to adding the upstream "Extract table":

[image: Tested scenarios]

What is the problem and how can we solve it? I could enable load in the upstream table to solve the issue but I don't see why a select would give us a 429 error. I would be glad to provide more information.